# Parse JSON Data using POJO, Where key name is numeric

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I'm trying to parse a special JSON data using Wrapper class, special means a JSON which have numeric keys like below :

```
{
"date":"2018-11-01",
"hours":"01-Nov 08:00",
"1011":"837.7500",
"1022":"99.92596979567664",
"1010":"3.198083",
"1021":"5",
"1019":"1171.000",
"1018":"3.578371",
"1017":"30.46989",
"1016":"0.0001931423",
"1015":"6749",
"1014":"0.161805",
"1013":"0.001678397",
"1012":"1.406077"
}
```

I know how to parse `JSON` data using `POJO`, But in this case java is not accepting the numeric as Keys.

> Wrapper/POJO Class

[image]

I don't want to go with JSON object based parsing. Is Anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: what did you write so far ?

Comment: `(String) jsonObject.get(yourNumber.toString());` doesn't work?

Comment: @OussemaAroua: i want to write a wrapper class for it. how i can write it?

Comment: @procrastinator: As i said i don't want to go with JSON Object based parsing.

Comment: you didn't try anything ? what you mean by "i don't want to go with JSON Object based parsing" ?

Comment: @OussemaAroua :I have tried a-lot but, Every time its compile time error because its not accepting String's object name as numeric.

Comment: Try Gson's `@SerializedName` feature. E.g. `@SerializedName("1011") double lat;`

Comment: Seems Helpful, let me check first!

Comment: @Enzokie : Thanks dear you save my time, its working, you can post an answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library has `SerializedName` functionality in which it parses the corresponding value of the key defined in SerializeName's parameter. Things will be tougher if your key is a pure integer since Java disallows it as variable name, in this case SerializeName will save you from that headache and it makes your code way more maintainable.

Example usage :

```
@SerializedName("1011") double lat;
@SerializedName("1022") double lng;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Gson for create wrapper class

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

```
public class Example {
 @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("hours")
    @Expose
    private String hours;
    @SerializedName("1011")
    @Expose
    private String _1011;
    @SerializedName("1022")
    @Expose
    private String _1022;

    public String getDate() {
    return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
    }

    public String getHours() {
    return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(String hours) {
    this.hours = hours;
    }

    public String get1011() {
    return _1011;
    }

    public void set1011(String _1011) {
    this._1011 = _1011;
    }

    public String get1022() {
    return _1022;
    }

    public void set1022(String _1022) {
    this._1022 = _1022;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code ,hope it works for you

```
JSONObject jsonObjectData = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("yourObject");
                        Iterator iterator = jsonObjectData.keys();
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
                            String key = (String) iterator.next();
                            yourClass.setKey(key);
                            yourClass.setVajue(jsonObjectData.getString(key));


                            yourList.add(yourClass);
                        }
```

Comment: thanks for answer but As i said i don't want to go with JSON Object based parsing. i want to Parse this data using wrapper class.